# Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://localhost :9002

Tags: java

this is my controller

```
package com.application.Controller;
import java.util.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import com.application.Contact.Contact;
import com.application.Entity.User;
import com.application.service.UserService;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate resttemplate;
    
    @GetMapping("/{userId}")
    public User getUser(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId) {
        
        User user = userService.getUser(userId);
        
        List contacts = this.resttemplate.getForObject("http://contact- 
          service/contact/"+user.getUserId(),List.class); 
        
        return user;
        
    }
```

I am trying to get the contacts as list from another MS.
I have registered both the MS on eureka server.

this is application property file for contact service and user service.
I am trying to use the service name instead of localhost:9002

Application.properties for user

```
server.port=9001

spring.application.name = user-service

eureka.server.hostname=localhost
```

Application.properties for contact

```
server.port=9002
spring.application.name = contact-service
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
```

Application.properties for Eureka server

```
server.port=8761

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false

eureka.client.fetch-registry=false

server.waitTimeinMsWhenSyncEmpty=0
```

It works if i directly use localhost:9002 in place of contact-service. in this line

```
List contacts = this.resttemplate.getForObject("http://contact- 
          service/contact/"+user.getUserId(),List.class);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.